# Exponential backoff CE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I hope someone can explain to me why SQL Server is giving me a different estimation than I expected.

My Reference link (http://sqlmag.com/database-development/optimization-tips-multiple-range-predicates-part-1)

25% of the table have `string = 'C'`, 10% have  `number = 9`. 25,000 do actually have `string = 'C' AND number = 9` but as per the Exponential backoff CE the estimated number of rows should be 50000. However, I am getting  25000.

[image: Execution Plan]

**Test Script**

```
SELECT keycol, string, number
FROM dbo.TStrNum
WHERE string = 'C' AND number = 9
```

**Statistics**

[DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQoIC.png)

**Test server**: SQL server 2016

**Compatibility Level** :130

**Sample Data generation script**

I used the same script provided in the reference link to test. This is below

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.GetNums', N'IF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNums;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNums(@low AS BIGINT, @high AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  WITH
    L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS D(c)),
    L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
    L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
    L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
    L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
    L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
    Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
            FROM L5)
  SELECT TOP(@high - @low + 1) @low + rownum - 1 AS n
  FROM Nums
  ORDER BY rownum;
GO


IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.TStrNum', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.TStrNum;

CREATE TABLE dbo.TStrNum
(
  keycol INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  string VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  number INT         NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO dbo.TStrNum WITH (TABLOCK) (string, number)
  SELECT
    CHAR(ASCII('A') + S.n) AS string,
    N.n AS number
  FROM dbo.GetNums(0, 3) AS S
    CROSS JOIN dbo.GetNums(1, 10) AS N
    CROSS JOIN dbo.GetNums(1, 25000) AS M;

-- Indexes
 CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_str_num ON dbo.TStrNum(string, number, keycol);
    -- Indexes

-- Trigger creation of histogram on second index key
SELECT keycol, string, number
FROM dbo.TStrNum
WHERE number = 9 AND number % 2 = 0;


-- Update statistics with full scan
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.TStrNum WITH FULLSCAN;
GO
```

Comment: Get rid of the index `idx_str_num` and the estimated rows are around 50,000 so the stats on the multi column index are being used. Presumably it uses these in preference to combining individual selectivities with  exponential backoff if available.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE8e6.png

Comment: Martin, Now I am totally confused. I am getting execution plan with Table scan with 25000 as the estimated row. Could you explain it in details, please?

Comment: Also, you spilled water on  whatever I learned so far from this link as well (https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/sql-plan/cardinality-estimation-for-multiple-predicates)

Comment: If you run the "Sample Data generation script" at the bottom of your question but with the `CREATE INDEX` commented out you get estimated 25k?

Comment: I dropped that index and tested it. Still getting same 25000. Please see the links below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B69206ROf0EjQmJDVm1pSjFCVXM/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B69206ROf0EjcGdtU1BEX3FidVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't see the plan. It says "Owner prevented downloads for this audio file."

Comment: Updated the permission. Please check it now.

Comment: That plan is using `CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70"` - this is not the new cardinality estimator.

Comment: Oops I might have flipped it old CE model while playing with it.Sorry to waste your time, I will check it let you know. Many thanks